Ошибка Process finished with exit code 0
При запуске скрипта ничего не происходит. Просто молчание, а после моей остановки скрипта выходит это оповещение
/Users/digram/Documents/Ai/subscribe_parcing/venv/bin/python /Users/digram/Documents/Ai/subscribe_parcing/subscribe/20.05_1.py
Process finished with exit code 0
Как узнать, в чем ошибка? Уже пробовал в ChatGPT, другими ИИ узнать причину - все вокруг да около.

Process finished with exit code 0 - это не ошибка, данное сообщение означает что код был выполнен без ошибок

Вы бы хоть код приложили какой-то.

https://pastebin.com/6RbzX5G5

Да, ошибка нулевая, вроде скрипт без ошибок, но реально ничего не происходит
